# Scraping JS pages with selenium/bs4

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape instagram(No I'm not using the api) hashtags with selenium & bs4 but keep getting the error:

"Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

I've tried waiting for the page to load but no matter what I do I either get a blank print statement or that error. I've searched and found a couple answer's that are outdated so I decided to finally ask here.

```
def scrape(browser):

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/")
tag = input("Enter a hashtag you would like to search: ")

# ig search bar
search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('._9x5sw')
if tag != '#':
    search.send_keys('#' + tag)
else:
    search.send_keys(tag)

# scrape IG hash tags
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
time.sleep(5)
for soup in soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_k2vj6'}):
    print(soup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work (using both firefox and phantomjs)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tag = input("Enter a hashtag you would like to search: ")
    url = 'https://www.instagram.com/instagram/'
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('<yourPathToPhantomJS>')
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
    # driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(url)
    search = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input')
    if tag != '#':
        search[0].click()
        search[0].send_keys('#' + tag)
    else:
        search[0].send_keys(tag)
    time.sleep(10)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_k2vj6'})
    for link in links:
        print(link)
```

Two nits:

- I had to set the browser's window size for it to work in phantomJS
- For a few of my tests, five seconds was not long enough for the dropdown to load.

Comment: thanks man worked! So the problem was letting the page load a little longer than 5 sec? Also why a index of [0] on the search variable?

Comment: If you were using phantomJS then the problem was likely that the window size needed to trigger something in the page to activate the input tag. Before I added that line, I was getting the same error as you were. And, the index [0] on search is simply because I used `find_elements_by_tag_name` instead of `find_element_by_tag_name`.

Answer (score 1):

This how-to make it live DOM and loaded js so, Enjoy and Save your time searching, the idea is to get the whole body, if you want also head do replace the body, It will be exactly as selenium get.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
dri = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
html = dri.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
```